# php array to call wordpress get_current_user_info

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've been reading and tweaking code for three days and can't figure this out. Because I'm new to php. The developer that wrote this php login script didn't code it for WordPress and not for an automatic login like I need. I think I've figured out the automatic login at the end of the code I didn't post here.

He created this code for his array that will have set values for the three api strings that never change, but I need to include the logged in WordPress user's username and password to be included in his array. The array info is passed by xml later in the script. This is for an automated SSL login to another server and when an image is clicked it runs the php code.

This is the code I just got from him, but I don't believe it's correct because all of the colors just changed in Notepad++ when I inserted it:

```
// Set the Query POST parameters - array    
$query_vals = array(
'api_username' => 'api-username-goes-here',
'api_password' => 'password-here', 
'api_key' => 'api-key-here’,
'username' => $current_user[‘user_login’],
'password' => $current_user[‘user_pass’]        
);
```

I know the last two lines can't be correct. What's the correct code to access the WordPress get user variables to use with his array?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this would be better on [Wordpress Stack](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You need to use `'`. Not `‘` and `’`.

Answer (score 0):

Change ‘ to '

```
// Set the Query POST parameters
$query_vals = array(
'api_username' => 'api-username-goes-here',
'api_password' => 'password-here', 
'api_key' => 'api-key-here',
'username' => $current_user['user_login'],
'password' => $current_user['user_pass']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this somewhere in your code first:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

Then you'll want to change your array to stuff like this:

```
'username' => $current_user->user_login
```

Comment: The only problem I see is that I don't want to screw up the other part of the developer's code that needs to get passed to the xml. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: You're just changing the way you set values in the array. The end result is still an array so it shouldn't mess anything up. Backup up the original file if you are worried about it for a quick fix if things break.